# Add class to li-Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to add a class or id to the last list element. But it do not work. (with no error message):

```
<div id="preistabelle">
 <ul class="pricing-cols">
   <li class=pricing-col three-table "></li>
   <li class=pricing-col three-table featured plan "></li>
   <li class=pricing-col three-table "></li>
</div>


 <script>
 $(".pricing-cols ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
 </script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your HTML code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it for you. You had a lot errors in your html code.

### HTML:

```
<div id="preistabelle">
    <ul class="pricing-cols">
        <li class="pricing-col three-table "></li>
        <li class="pricing-col three-table featured plan "></li>
        <li class="pricing-col three-table ">test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $(".pricing-cols li:last-child").addClass("last");
});
```

### CSS (only for testing)

```
.last {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2yZJJ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pricing-cols ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
```

This selected a ul inside .pricing-cols when .pricing-cols is the ul, change to:

```
$(".pricing-cols li:last-child").addClass("last");
```